# How to create dynamic cards of html on the basis of ajax data

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm retrieving the data from ajax successfully but there is a problem that is it also retrieve the address in json format so I want to show the all addresses  in separate separate cards.I have show my desired output and also the output I got the code below I'm using:-

HTML

```
<div class="card-container-clearfix">
 <div class="location-list">

 </div>
</div>
```

CSS of `location-list`

```
.location-list{
    float: left;
    width:23%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Ajax success response

```
success: function(response){
      $('#name').html(response.response.total_record[0].first_name+" "+response.response.total_record[0].last_name);
      $('#first').val(response.response.total_record[0].first_name);
      $('#last').val(response.response.total_record[0].last_name);
      $('#phone').val(response.response.total_record[0].phone_number);
      $('#alternative').val(response.response.total_record[0].alternative_number);
      $('#id').val(response.response.total_record[0]._id);
      $.each(response.response.total_record[0].address,function(i,item){
            $('.location-list').append('<header class="header_title"><h3>Location:</h3></header><div class="location-detial"><p><span id='+response.response.total_record[0].address[i]._id+'>'+response.response.total_record[0].address[i].address+'</span></p></div>');
      });
}
```

desired output:-

[image]

The output I got:-

[image]

How I will make my desired output can anybody will help me. if this is a basic question then sorry because I just started learning about it. Thank you